# Where can I find highest resolution soil data from public domain in India?

Tags: data-request, india, soils

Are there any soil data sources for the modeling of flood hazard or flood inundation for India?

Comment: What do you mean by "soil data"? Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_cover ? Is land cover enough, or do you also need elevation?

Comment: Do you need the full data for all of India, or just a typical sample of 1 square kilometer?

Comment: Thanks for replying..it seems that I am no longer interested in soil data.